# How can I install PAW-Ubuntu plymouth theme on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

Is there any way, how I can install PAW-Ubuntu plymouth theme on ubuntu 16.04? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Plymouth theme folders seem to have changed in 16.04 (compared to 14.04). Previously they were in `/lib/plymouth/themes`; now they are in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`. Even though themes installed in the old folders are listed as installed (`sudo update-alternatives --list default.plymouth`), they don’t seem to work properly.

The .deb file for this theme (assuming you mean [this version](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=158162)) assumes the old folders so you will need to open it using Archive Manager, then open the `data.tar.gz` file inside it. Drill down until you get to the  `paw` folder and extract it somewhere.

Open `paw/paw.plymouth` in a text editor and change these lines…

```
[script]
ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/paw
ScriptFile=/lib/plymouth/themes/paw/paw.script
```

…to…

```
[script]
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/paw
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/paw/paw.script
```

Open a terminal in the folder where you extracted the `paw` folder and copy it:

```
sudo cp -a paw /usr/share/plymouth/themes
```

Next ‘install’ it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/paw/paw.plymouth 100
```

Then choose it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

To test (change number of seconds at `I<10`):

```
sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0; I<10; I++)); do sleep 1 ; sudo plymouth --update=test$I ; done ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

Comment: What is the reason for the 'for' loop?

Comment: I think I copied that code from somewhere. It looks like you could just use $I after sleep without the loop, but bash scripting doesn’t always work out they way you’d expect. I have a vague memory that it didn’t work without the loop. I haven’t used Ubuntu on my main PC in a few years, but I’d be surprised if this was still valid.