# How to change boot splash screen in 18.04

Tags: boot, plymouth

I have done this in the past in 16.04 and 17.10 but in 18.04 I can not get plymouth manager to work.  Downloaded it from the software center but it doesn't work.  Is there a guide available that will let me do it in terminal?

Comment: i have successfully installed this playmouth theme in 18.04 https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1230234/

Comment: Doh! I didn’t realise you were talking about plymouth *manager* (rather than plymouth). I had trouble with it and found the command line much more reliable. See the answer below.

Answer (score 24):

The [same methods described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770295/how-can-i-install-paw-ubuntu-plymouth-theme-on-ubuntu-16-04/870092#870092), do still work in 18.04.

**NB:** between 14.04 and 16.04 the location of Plymouth themes changed to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`. If you have an old theme its `.plymouth` file might point to `/lib/plymouth/themes/`.

#### Installing a new theme

Easy if it's packaged - `sudo apt install`

Otherwise you need to copy its folder or extract its archive to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`. Then you need to `install` it...

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/THEME/THEME.plymouth 100
```

...replacing THEME with the theme name.

#### Choosing the theme

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

#### Testing

You can also test Plymouth without rebooting...

```
sudo apt install plymouth-x11

sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0; I<10; I++)); do sleep 1 ; sudo plymouth --update=test$I ; done ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

Comment: Thank you.  I finally got it to go OK.  Biggest problem seems to be that it was an old splash screen and I couldn't remember how I had made it work in 17.10.  There must be an easy way to migrate or change them from the old /lib/plymouth/themes to the new path but I don't know what that is.  Went through and edited every reference in every file and that worked but was time consuming.