# Remnant boot animation from Ubuntu GNOME 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, boot

For many upgrades now (I'm currently on 18.04 desktop), I've had [this](https://www.distroscreens.com/2016/04/ubuntu-gnome-1604-xenial-xerus.html) boot animation (see third image with the two intertwined N's in circle) at boot and at shutdown. Not sure what it is or where it came from, but I don't need it anymore. How can I remove it?

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/a/1046396/231142

Comment: How is this related? And what should I do if it is?

Comment: The boot animation is called The Plymouth screen.  That shows how to change it.

Comment: Are these telling me how to remove it? They seem to be telling me how to upgrade it.

Comment: I guess they are not as straight forward, but basically you can install the `plymouth-themes` by running `sudo apt install plymouth-themes` then you run that `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` to choose what theme you want for the start up.  Of you can be like me and remove `splash` and `quiet` from the `/etc/default/grub` and that way you see just the text and no plymouth at all.