# Does Ubuntu have a Kernel Splash Screen? If so, how to enable it?

Tags: kernel, screen, plymouth

Hi I am creating a custom distro based off of Ubuntu 19.04 server.

I am looking for a way to enable a custom kernel splash screen.

Please let me know if this is possible, thanks.

Comment: So it can be done in Manjaro. https://youtu.be/2Mb3gb7wspI

Comment: You meant a boot splash screen? That is done with "plymouth" https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046370/how-to-change-boot-splash-screen-in-18-04 as an example

Comment: No I mean a kernel splash screen, not plymouth. https://youtu.be/2Mb3gb7wspI there is an example of what I mean. Here is a link to the manjaro forum for the kernel splash screen. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bootsplash-provided-by-the-kernel/34467/170

Comment: I only saw a `plymouth` screen also called 'boot splash' on the youtube video you linked. You use `splash` on the kernel line [in grub] to make the plymouth screen show on booting.

Answer (score 0):

## Grub Theme

What you are looking for is a [Grub Theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/109/) that runs before the kernel loads with Plymouth splash screen:

Here's my Grub Theme which is a spin on **Tux** theme referenced in your links:

[image: grub boot.gif]

Comment: No that's not what I am looking for.