# How to force change the Ubuntu splash screen (18.04)

Tags: xubuntu, themes, mate, plymouth

All other answers refer to update alternatives. I have read and tried most of those solutions, here and elsewhere. It did not work.

I originally installed Ubuntu-Mate 18.04. Didn't like Mate, installed XFCE-desktop.

Ever since, I could not change the splash screen back to xubuntu-logo. (Currently on 18.04.6)
I've tried (using update-alternatives)

- reinstall xubuntu-logo plymouth theme
- manually edit plymouth config in /usr/share/plymouth/themes
- installed other themes
- switched themes
- removed mate-logo theme
- physically removed the Mate theme folders (using cli)
  Each time, running `update-initramfs -u`.

***No change***. Shutdown shows a different logo, but boot up made no change whatsoever.

What am I missing?

edit: Correction - I did not use Plymouth manager. I just managed it with update-alternatives.
edit: As I said, all other SIMILAR questions does not solve the problem. Not here. Not anywhere else.
edit: Update-grub has run a thousand times since then after software updates.

edit: I realise that due to linux's infinite flexibility, not a single person's installation will match another's. My problem could be caused by any of a million things/tweaks/updates/etc I did to mine. I can't realistically expect there to be a generic answer to this question. But it was worth a shot. Guess I'll have to live with it till the next upgrade.

Comment: After changing the themes etc . ( And confirmed that it has been changes but not showing up) run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot splash screen in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046370/how-to-change-boot-splash-screen-in-18-04)

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -u` didn't this worked ? What is the output of this ?